# How to configure a gateway's DHCP and DNS to resolve hosts with the same hostname but different vlan domains?

Tags: linux, networking, dns, dhcp, vlan

A local network 192.168.1.0/24 has vlans  '*datacenter*' 10.10.10.0/24 and '*staging*' 10.10.20.0/24. Hosts are created in each of these vlans with identical hostnames, such as '*example.datacenter*' and '*example.staging*'.  Addresses are currently managed using static IPs and a "Local DNS Record" is manually set in the gateway.

I would like reconfigure the network to DHCP and delegate address management to the main gateway that already provides DHCP and DNS services.

Everything works normally when the first host is created (e.g. *example.datacenter*) but as soon as I create a second host with the same hostname in a different vlan (e.g. *example.staging*), DNS stops working.  The desired functionality is for each host to receive an IP from its assigned vlan and be resolvable from any other computer using the same main gateway for DNS.

How can I troubleshoot this issue in this specific environment:

- The *gateway* 192.168.1.1 is a unifi UDM Pro with many vlan networks created.  The vlans are configured with specific "Domain Name" such as

  - *datacenter*
  - *staging*
- Two testing containers created on Proxmox:

|  | CT200 | CT300 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Hostname | example | example |
| DNS domain | staging | datacenter |
| Bridge | vmbr1 | vmbr1 |
| Vlan Tag | 1020 | 10 |

The following testing procedures show the problem

| Testing Step | On CT200 Node example.staging | On CT300 Node example.datacenter | From workstation on 'localdomain' vlan |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CT 300 is started Appears on UDM Pro gateway: name: *example* VLAN ID = 10 IP address: 10.10.10.212 | (off) | `hostname -f` example.datacenter `ip -4 addr show eth0` (...) inet 10.10.10.212/24 brd 10.10.10.255 scope global dynamic eth0 (...) `cat /etc/resolv.conf` # --- BEGIN PVE --- search datacenter nameserver 10.10.10.42 nameserver 10.10.10.41 # --- END PVE --- `cat /etc/hosts` 127.0.0.1 localhost ::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback ff02::1 ip6-allnodes ff02::2 ip6-allrouters # --- BEGIN PVE --- 127.0.1.1 example.datacenter example | `nslookup example 192.168.1.1` Server: 192.168.1.1 Address: 192.168.1.1#53 Name: example Address: 10.10.10.212 `nslookup example.datacenter 192.168.1.1` Server: 192.168.1.1 Address: 192.168.1.1#53 Name: example.datacenter Address: 10.10.10.212 `nslookup example.staging 192.168.1.1` ** server can't find example.staging: NXDOMAIN `nslookup example.localdomain 192.168.1.1` ** server can't find example.localdomain: NXDOMAIN |
| CT 200 is started Appears on UDM Pro gateway: name: *example* VLAN ID = 1020 IP address: 10.10.20.241 | `hostname -f` example.staging `ip -4 addr show eth0` 2: eth0@if82: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000 link-netnsid 0 inet 10.10.20.241/24 brd 10.10.20.255 scope global dynamic eth0 valid_lft 86183sec preferred_lft 86183sec `cat /etc/resolv.conf` # --- BEGIN PVE --- search staging nameserver 10.10.10.42 nameserver 10.10.10.41 # --- END PVE --- `cat /etc/hosts` 127.0.0.1 localhost ::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback ff02::1 ip6-allnodes ff02::2 ip6-allrouters # --- BEGIN PVE --- 127.0.1.1 example.staging example # --- END PVE --- | (running) | `nslookup example 192.168.1.1` Server: 192.168.1.1 Address: 192.168.1.1#53 Name: example Address: 10.10.20.241 `nslookup example.datacenter 192.168.1.1` Server: 192.168.1.1 Address: 192.168.1.1#53 *** Can't find example.datacenter: No answer `nslookup example.staging 192.168.1.1` Server: 192.168.1.1 Address: 192.168.1.1#53 Name: example.staging Address: 10.10.20.241 `nslookup example.localdomain 192.168.1.1` Server: 192.168.1.1 Address: 192.168.1.1#53 ** server can't find example.localdomain: NXDOMAIN |

These two containers appear on UDM Pro with the same name but as two separate client devices that have different IP addresses and vlan assignments.  From the external workstations, DNS stops working for *example.datacenter* when *example.staging* appears.  There are no meaningful logs on UDM Pro to I can locate.

[UDM Pro Client Devices Excerpt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPXWb.png)

In this network, it is important to have the staging vlan  be a mirror of the datacenter in order to fully test a collection of servers before promoting a server configuration to the live, datacenter environment.  The static-IP assignment approach has been fine, but is becoming too complicated and brittle.

How can this DHCP configuration be realized?